# I have N*M matrix and two 1*M row vectors I want to vectorize mathematical operations on them

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have N by M matrix A , a 1 by M matrix or a row vector B
and another 1 by M row vector C. Can I vectorize the following code more than that?

```
for i = 1:N
     A(i,:) = (A(i,:)-B)./C;
end;
```

and what about more general case where we have K by M matrices(K divisible by N) instead of vectors

Comment: I updated my answer according to your update. You didn't specify how you exactly want to generalize your problem, I used a convenient interpretation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) was designed to do:

```
A = bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,A,B),C);
```

It will automatically expand the arrays of size `[1 M]` to be compatible with the one of size `[N M]`, then perform the necessary array operations on them, returning an array of size `[N M]`.

If your `B` and `C` arrays are of size `[K M]`, then it's a bit more difficult. You didn't specify what the output should be shaped, but in the most general case you can compute "(A-B)/C" for every row of `B` and `C` and collect these matrices in an array of size `[K N M]`:

```
A = bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,permute(A,[3 1 2]),permute(B,[1 3 2])),permute(C,[1 3 2]));
```

where `A` is transformed to an array of size `[1 N M]`, and both `B` and `C` are transformed to size `[K 1 M]`. Depending on the size of your arrays along the various dimensions, you might benefit from putting `M` in front (since that's the dimension along which you're subtracting, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need raw speed, I would prefer a more explicit approach:

```
N = size(A, 1);
easy = (A-repmat(B, N, 1)) ./ repmat(C, N, 1);
```

`repmat` copies the first argument, the number of second argument times vertically (in rows), and they number of third argument times in columns.  So, in this case, B is turned into N x M by replicating the vector N times vertically only.

For the more general case, where B & C are K x M, and N/K is an integer:

```
rowReps = size(A, 1)/size(B, 1);
notMuchHarder= (A - repmat(B, rowReps , 1) ./ repmat(C, rowReps, 1);
```